# How do I remove the anchor in the url after a form submission?

Tags: forms, symfony, anchor

In Symfony 2.7, I use anchors on my index page. The page also contains a form that allows me to filter the elements displayed.
If I navigate within the page using the anchors, an anchor appears in the URL.
Then, if I click on the form's submit button, filters are applied and page refreshed with new content.
Problem is the anchor in the URL doesn't disappear during the process, and after refresh, the page scrolls down to the last anchor I visited.
How can I reset the URL after form's submission?

Here's my action code:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $dailyPlanning = $em
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Planning')
        ->findOneBy(array('day' => (new \DateTime)));
    //....//
    $filter = new Filter($param, $param2);
    $form = $this->createForm(new FilterType(), $filter);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $dailyPlanning->applyFilter($filter);
    }
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Workflow:index.html.twig', array(
      'planning' => $dailyPlanning,
      'form'     => $form->createView(),
      'filterHidden' => $filter->allChecked(),
    ));
}
```

Comment: Just specify form action attribute. Do not lay on current url.

Comment: Just redirect after submission.

Comment: @Cerad Thanks for your suggestion. I've edited my question, putting a bit of code. I need to pass objects to the view, so I can't just redirect.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for your help. Where do I do this?

Comment: In html template: <form action>.
If you use form builder: look at this entry http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#changing-the-action-and-method-of-a-form.

Comment: If you don't redirect then the anchor is not going away no matter what you do in the server.

Comment: @Cerad So, no solution? Isn't it possible then to prevent the anchor from appearing in the url in the first place?

Comment: The solution is to redirect.  I see nothing in your posted code that would prevent you from saving a "applyFilter" flag and the parameters in the session and then redirecting with a clean url.

Comment: It's also unclear why you have the anchors in the first place.  @Alex approach would get rid of them as well.

Comment: @Cerad. Thanks for your time. The anchors appear in the url because my page is meant to be navigated through this way. And (this is optional) user can decide to filter the content. If he does so after having used an anchor, it's still there in the url.
Saving my filtered dailyPlanning object in session variables before redirecting is an option, I just wanted to keep it simple and thought there would be an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda old question ... but better late than never :) Tested on Symfony 5.4

```php
<?php
/**
 * @Route("/contac", name="contact", methods={"GET", "POST"})
*/
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    // ...
    $form = $this->createForm(new FilterType(), $filter, [
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('contact')
    ]);
    // ...
```

This will force URL to be recreated after submit, the original one will not be used.